# How to disable cache for AWS EKS managed coredns addon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, coredns

Recently I'm facing `No Route to Host` errors on my application while pods are scaling down. I'm suspecting `CoreDNS cache`, and when I try to disable it in `Corefile` in CoreDNS configmap, it's reverted back after some time.
I couldn't manage to overwrite default values. It keeps bringing back the old value. In github there is an issue about this
(https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1597), other people are suffering from this as well. I'm wondering if there is a workaround to succeed this operation?

Thank you very much,

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the addon from EKS managed to self-manage, there are [3 ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-coredns.html#removing-coredns-eks-add-on) to do this.